# radio button condition based on selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button with an `id="pay"` and a function that i need to be executed if the radio buttton is selected.Any help?

```
function getMn() {
    var int = document.getElementById("pay").value;
    return int;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="pay" value="pass" onClick="getMn(this.value)"/>
```

or If you dont want value to be passed to function and only execute function then you can simply call function

```
<input type="radio" id="pay" value="pass" onClick="getMn()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a click event to the radio button, and check whether it is selected...

```
document.getElementById('pay').onclick = function(){ 
    if(document.getElementById('pay').checked) {
      //call your function here
    }
};
```